# Convert Ruby String to utf-16be | Ruby Equivalent Code of Python

Tags: python, ruby, unicode-string

I'm trying to send Bengali text using an SMS Gateway. However it doesn't normally support Bengali text. Their documentation says I need to convert the SMS string to utf-16be; without any other details. However I found a **Python** implementation of what I'm looking for [here](https://adhikary.net/en/2019/07/15/encoding-bangla-unicode-sms-for-sslwireless-in-python/) .

```
>>> message = 'আমার সোনার বাংলা'
>>> message
'আমার সোনার বাংলা'

>>> message.encode('utf-16-be')
b'\t\x86\t\xae\t\xbe\t\xb0\x00 \t\xb8\t\xcb\t\xa8\t\xbe\t\xb0\x00 \t\xac\t\xbe\t\x82\t\xb2\t\xbe'

>>> message.encode('utf-16-be').hex()
'098609ae09be09b0002009b809cb09a809be09b0002009ac09be098209b209be'

>>> message.encode('utf-16-be').hex().upper()
'098609AE09BE09B0002009B809CB09A809BE09B0002009AC09BE098209B209BE'
```

I am trying to accomplish two things here:

- **Understand the Python Implementation**
- **Replicate the same procedure in Ruby 2.6**

So far I've come up with following

```
text = 'আমার সোনার বাংলা'.encode("UTF-16BE")
p text
#output-> "\u0986\u09AE\u09BE\u09B0 \u09B8\u09CB\u09A8\u09BE\u09B0 \u09AC\u09BE\u0982\u09B2\u09BE"
```

Comment: What do you see with:  text = 'আমার সোনার বাংলা'.encode("UTF-8")   ??

Comment: "আমার সোনার বাংলা" is the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically converting from a string to bytes is accomplished with the [`unpack`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-unpack) method:

```
# ref unpack documentation for specifics, but I use 'H*' here for hex
message.encode('utf-16-be').unpack('H*')
```